# Agora publish stream not working properly

Tags: java, android, agora.io

```
            mRtcEngine.addPublishStreamUrl(URL, true);

LiveTranscoding config = new LiveTranscoding();
            config.audioSampleRate = TYPE_44100;
            config.audioChannels = 2;
            config.audioBitrate = 48;
            config.width = 360;
            config.height = 640;
            config.videoBitrate = 400;
            config.videoFramerate = 15;
            config.videoCodecProfile = HIGH;
            LiveTranscoding.TranscodingUser user = new LiveTranscoding.TranscodingUser();
            user.uid = uid;
            user.x = 0;
            user.audioChannel = 0;
            user.y = 0;
            user.width = 640;
            user.height = 720;
            config.addUser(user);
```

This method.. i'm calling for stream URL in agroa rtc engine but it's randomly working not working properly. some time it throwing timeout exceptions.

Comment: Can you share the relevant logs? What kind of error are you getting? What platform are you streaming to? Are you streaming only 1 host or are multiple clients streaming to this url at the same time?

Comment: it's throwing time out exception (RTMP_STREAM_PUBLISH_ERROR_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT(3)) randomly and trying to streaming Facebook rtmp url using addPublishStreamUrl method.

Comment: we are streaming only 1 host

Comment: Can you post your transcoding config?

Comment: Hi @Samyak I was edited my question above with transcoding config. can you please check this.

Comment: Are you making sure this is called in the onJoinChannelSuccess callback? Are you making sure to call mRtcEngine.setLiveTranscoding(config); before calling publish?

Comment: Yes @Samyak we calling this in onJoinChannelSuccess callback

Comment: Have you made sure to call mRtcEngine.setLiveTranscoding(config);?

Comment: And you need to make sure to call mRtcEngine.addPublishStreamUrl only after you have called the setLiveTranscoding method.

Comment: Yeah @Samyak we're calling this addPublishStreamUrl method after setLiveTranscoding.

Comment: Can you test your Facebook url with OBS? Is it working consistently there? When using Agora, my understanding is that it works sometimes but not always, correct?

Comment: Yes it's working randomly

Comment: The integration looks correct to me. I would recommend you file a support ticket on https://agora-ticket.agora.io/

Comment: Did you fix this? it works fine in the last three days... but sometimes it's not working.